# generic::failed_precondition: Record leaf types are not supported

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting this error in google Bigquery 'generic::failed_precondition: Record leaf types are not supported.' while trying to insert records in Bigquery table using Java API, the data is coming from a select query which I have executed through JobConfigurationQuery.

In my table structure I have Record type column within a Record type column.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: job id? query? anything we could use to debug?

Comment: Please edit your question to show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).